# Is there any way to track log in/log out timing on Onepanel?

Tags: amazon-eks, cvat

I've installed Onepanel on my EKS cluster and I want to run CVAT tool there. I want to keep track on user log in-log out activities and timings. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Onepanel isn't supported anymore as far as I know. It has an outdated version of CVAT. CVAT has analytics functionality: https://opencv.github.io/cvat/v2.2.0/docs/manual/advanced/analytics/. It can show working time and intervals of activity.

Comment: Great! But how do I install CVAT without onepanel? Is there any other solution? I’m installing it on AWS EKS clusters

Comment: forgot to tag you @nikman